# The system cannot find the file specified exception

Tags: c#, dll, task-parallel-library, .net-assembly, gac

I am using `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` in my API project. I have added reference of this dll from GAC but still I am getting file not found exception when I run my unit test . The exception message is:

> Test Error    TestError   363 Test method TestProject.UnitTest1.SendMessage
>   threw exception: 
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The
>   composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is
>   provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
>   more detailed information.
>
> 1) Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow,
>   Version=0.0.4303.21337, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance
>   of type 'SomeObject'.

I cannot understand why it is not loading the dll from GAC?

Comment: How exactly did you add that DLL to GAC? And how are you referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

Because there might be an assembly with that name in de GAC, but the version, culture, processor architecture and/or public key token are different. The identity of an assembly consists of all these items, not just the name of an assembly.

Comment: No other assembly with the same name. I have searched it in entire windows folder

Comment: Ok, but does the assembly you do find have the exact version, culture and public key token as mentioned in the error message? use a tool like gacutil to check

Comment: It is exactly the same assembly that i have referenced

Comment: Then maybe your unit test runner is not .Net 4.0. Try looking in the fusion log to learn more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx